# how to get the RichTextBox that the user is writing?

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I tried the following code:

```
  public RichTextBox GetCurrentlyInUse()
        {
            if (p.Focused)
            {
                return p;
            }
            else if (r.Focused)
            {
                return r;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

but ever returns `null`,how I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are u trying to get the text in rich Text box .. ?

Comment: Not, I need get the rich box currently in use for handling it in .SelectionXX methods.

Comment: Do you execute this pressing a button?

Comment: Could it be because you're hopelessly confused by the dreadful variable names?  Look at the Form.ActiveControl property.

Comment: Since we have no idea what `p` and `r` are, this code is meaningless to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new field to your `Form` class:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form {

    private RichTextBox currentRichTextBox = null;

    //...
}
```

Add both these events to each of your `richTextBoxes`:

```
private void richTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    currentRichTextBox = (RichTextBox) sender;
}

private void richTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    currentRichTextBox = null;
}

// Add those events to richTextBox2, richTextBox3...
```

This way, you will always have in the `currentRichTextBox` object the value of the currently used `richTextBox` or `null` if no `richTextBox` is active.